# Python could not detect OpenCv installed in my system

Tags: python, linux, opencv

I installed opencv 4.3.0 from the source. It was installed sucessfully. 
`pkg-config --modversion opencv4` gives the output `4.3.0` . But when i try to import cv2 module in pythone it says cv2 module not found. I have Linux(Debian) in my system with python 3.8.

Comment: When you `cmake` those sources, did you check if python3 bindings were enabled? The useful variables are `BUILD_opencv_python3` and all those starting with `PYTHON3_`. 
Also verify that your `PYTHONPATH` is coherent with the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` you used.

Answer (score 0):

Likely has to do with where the package was installed. If you used apt-get, I would recommend removing and trying with `pip install opencv-python`. Aside from that, you can also try running `sudo python3` and then importing.

hope that helps!

Comment: Is not there a way to use already installed opencv which is latest version(4.3.0), but pip installs old version 4.2.0?

Comment: You can specify version `pip install opencv-python==4.3.0`